# mysql table or csv file for mobile emergency numbers with country code

Tags: mysql, csv

I want emergency mobile contact list like.. 911 as per country name or code in mysql table or csv file so that I can make table in database and can use it in my application

Please let me know if you are aware of it
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a data mining forum.

Comment: okay but I just want some hint if anyone can help @ iqstatic

Comment: I don't think this is the place to ask for that, it has *nothing* to do with programming. In addition a simple search online provides [plenty of answers](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=0#complete=0&q=emergency+number+by+country). It is obvious you have not researched before asking, or that you don't know how to convert the results into a CSV file (which is another clue) or just you don't *want* to do it yourself. I vote to close this post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all country emergency numbers and have to make table manually. You can not get direct mysql table.

Comment: Actually I was looking such direct sql or csv file ok thanks for reply